# Laravel with google cloud Datastore

Tags: php, google-app-engine, laravel-5, google-cloud-datastore

How can I create CRUD in laravel using cloud datastore? and deploy my app on google cloud app engine.

Please give me direction to do that what requirements should I need?
what is my app.yaml for that and all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/laravel/ for initial Setup.

**Datastore** you can add via **[composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md)** and use it.

Example:
`composer require google/cloud-datastore`

More details: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php#google-cloud-datastore-ga